# Git pre-commit hook behavior with Intellij Idea

Tags: git, shell, intellij-idea, githooks

I have a monorepo project with pre-commit git hook that bumps version in `package.json` files. This hook uses the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

# See if git detects any changes for the given directory
if [[ -z `git diff --cached --shortstat ./packages/$1` ]]; then
    VERSION=`node -p -e "require('./packages/$1/package.json').version"`
    echo "$1 has not changed, old version: $VERSION"
    exit 0
fi

VERSION=$(cd packages/$1 && npm version patch --no-git-tag-version)
# Add package.json to staged
git add packages/$1/package.json > /dev/null
echo "$1 has changed, new version: ${VERSION//v}"
```

I change one file `tsconfig.json` in `backend` package and commit it via Idea UI, with "Run git hooks option checked". I only check this on file in UI dialog, but the hook should also bump package.json. In Idea version control console I see following log appear:

```
14:28:08.610: [myproject] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit --only -F /private/var/folders/rf/mnfmp6xs2zjb50x0nqfrlftw0000gn/T/git-commit-msg-.txt -- packages/backend/tsconfig.json
[master c5ec828] Hooks test 24
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Running `git log -1 --stat` says that package.json got changed by hook and was commited:

```
git log -1 --stat
commit c5ec8289afa8f15d7134b362992d4a91e31bda16 (HEAD -> master)
Author: doomsower <mail@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 13 14:28:08 2018 +0300

    Hooks test 24

 packages/backend/package.json  | 2 +-
 packages/backend/tsconfig.json | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

The `packages/backend/package.json` version was bumped by hook and is correct. However, when I run `git status` I see following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   packages/backend/package.json

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   packages/backend/package.json
```

Then I run `git add packages/backend/package.json` and after that `git status` returns:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I don't quite understand what's going on here:

1) According to logs, Idea ran `git commit` with `--only` flag and `package.json` was not specified in command line, yet it was commited. How is it possible?

2) Ok, so 2 files were committed and `package.json` was committed with bumped version number. How is it possible that after that git working tree is not clean and I have to run `git add` to make it clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think this is the timeline of events in your above situation:
 1. You change `tsconfig.json` and add it to the git index
 2. You then commit the index which only has `tsconfig.json`. Before the commit is run your hook modifies and adds `package.json` to the index.
 3. The index is then committed, specifying only to commit `tsconfig.json`. Normally this would leave `package.json` as staged but (and, full disclosure, I'm taking an educated guess here) because it was added in the hook git has already dome *some commit-processing* to the file.
4. This leaves you with your new `package.json` committed, the old `package.json` in the index, and the new one on your file system. Hence adding it back to the index *cancels out* the change, as it now matches the committed history - giving a clean repo.

The fix for this would be to remove the add from your pre-commit, and run the commit in your post-commit hook, like so:
`git add package.json`
`git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify`
Using `--no-verify` to prevent an infinite loop of hooks

Comment: Thank you! You solution helped, with one minor adjustment: --no-verify only disables pre-commit hook, and then post-commit hooks loops. But I was able to disable post-commit loop using this workaround: https://coderwall.com/p/dv-dgg/bypass-post-commit-hook-temporarily

Comment: Ahh ok, should have checked that. Glad it's working for you now :)